# Angular 2: Nested Check Boxes

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I would like to use check boxes to select a parent object and then only show check boxes for a a property (array) on that object.  For example i have an object of products and each product has a number of items.  I want to show the check list of all items in the product but only if the product itself has been checked.

I tried the following code by it either shows or hides the items based on the initial value - i want to be able to toggle the check box on and off and hide or display the items.

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index" #ref>
    <md-checkbox type="checkbox"> {{product.productTitle}}</md-checkbox>
    <div *ngIf="ref.checked">
       <div *ngFor="let item of product.items; let i = index">
          <md-checkbox type="checkbox">{{item.code}}</md-checkbox> - {{item.name}}
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Are your products defined within a FormArray?

Comment: Not currently, my plan is to take the selected items and display them in a form.  I can put the products into a form if that would help?

Comment: Do you mind posting the component code, or at least the formGroup declaration?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your previous comment. Your #ref is on your `div` and you are checking if it is checked. The div will never return true for checked correct? You need to reference your `<md-checkbox>` and check for checked there.

Comment: Of course - how silly of me.  That actually works exactly as i was expecting it to.  Late at night :-) thanks for the assistance

Comment: Ha, nice, I went ahead and posted the answer below for anyone who stumbles on it later. Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your #ref is on your div and you are checking if it is checked. The div will never return true for checked correct? You need to reference your  and check for `checked` there.

For example (Depending on how your md-checkbox component is configured):

```js
<div *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index">
    <md-checkbox type="checkbox" #ref> {{product.productTitle}}</md-checkbox>
    <div *ngIf="ref.checked">
       <div *ngFor="let item of product.items; let i = index">
          <md-checkbox type="checkbox">{{item.code}}</md-checkbox> - {{item.name}}
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```